# T-Sql Extract order number within a string

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I am simply trying to return the order number off of a string such as that listed below. I've tried charindex with left and right and substrings to no avail. Using the actual data the order number can be anywhere from 9 to 12 characters.

```
Declare @string varchar(max) = 'Your order number for this purchase is 012345678 and we appreciate your business'
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
M.Butter

Comment: Is the text always the same before and after number?

Comment: Look at SUBSTRING and RIGHT  especially if your text around the order number is the same.

Comment: Yes. So charindex('is' n 'and'). Simple I know but I'm on fourth beer.

Answer (score 0):

`PATINDEX` can be used to do regular expression search to find order number

**%[0-9]%**

once the index is found, SUBSTRING can be used to get the order number

```
declare @var varchar(max) = 'Your order number for this purchase is 012345678 and we appreciate your business'

declare @sub varchar(max)
select @sub=SUBSTRING(@var,patindex('%[0-9]%', @var), len(@var))

SELECT SUBSTRING(@sub, 0, charindex(' ', @sub))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I have two numbers in the string and just want the second one? declare @var varchar(max) = 'Your order number 888 for this purchase is 012345678 and we appreciate your business'       Want 012345678 returned.

Comment: @m. butter, will there be always two numbers and you want the second number

Comment: If you always want the last number from the string which may have 1 or more numbers like your example you can work of a reversed string and then reverse the result. REVERSE().